# Why are there different rewards for overcoming for the seven churches in Revelation 2 and 3?

Tags: revelation, prophecy, eschatology

Revelation 2:7

> To the angel of the church in Ephesus write:To him who overcomes, I will grant to ***eat of the tree of life*** which is in the Paradise of God.’

Revelation 2:8

> 8 “And to the angel of the church in Smyrna write:f]Be faithful until death, and I will give you the ***crown of life***.

Revelation 2:12

> 12 “And to the angel of the church in Pergamum write:To him who overcomes, to him I will give some of the ***hidden manna, and I will give him a white stone***, and a new name written on the stone which no one knows but he who receives it.

Revelation 2:18

> 18 “And to the angel of the church in Thyatira write:26 He who overcomes, and he who keeps My deeds until the end, ***to him I will give authority over the [o]nations;*** 27 and he shall [p]rule them with a rod of iron, as the vessels of the potter are broken to pieces,

Revelation 3:3

> 3 “To the angel of the church in Sardis write:5 He who overcomes will thus be clothed in ***white garments***; and I will not erase his name from the book of life, and I will confess his name before My Father and before His angels.

Revelation3:7:7

> 7 “And to the angel of the church in Philadelphia write:12 He who overcomes, I will make him a ***pillar in the temple*** of My God, and he will not go out from it anymore; and I will write on him the name of My God, and the name of the city of My God, the new Jerusalem, which comes down out of heaven from My God, and My new name.

Revelation 3:14

> 14 “To the angel of the church in Laodicea write:21 He who overcomes, I will grant to him to ***sit down with Me on My throne***, as I also overcame and sat down with My Father on His throne

it seems all who overcome are given somewhat different gifts

Could there be something significant why this gifts differ?

Comment: Have you considered that it would sound very repetitive and give a very narrow view of his Glory if he described it with the same words over and described it with the same words over and described it with the same words over and described it with the same words over again?

Comment: @Caleb,why then you use the same phrase 'who overcomes', thought this refers to different gifts

Comment: Some repetition establishes a pattern; full repetition risks seeming inartistic and dull. I doubt anyone enjoys reading Numbers 7:12-83 aloud. This isn't to say that repetition can't be artistic, but it's harder. Psalm 136 works, but it still needs a good reader to not butcher it.

Comment: @curiousdannii,is the author referring to one and same gifts/rewards to different over comers/churches?

Comment: I think this question is too broad since each of the Gatherings presents significant interpretative challenges. However, they are all discussed in this book:  https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=CGuOAAAAMAAJ&rdid=book-CGuOAAAAMAAJ&rdot=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this will answer the question but it will provide part of the answer.

With the exception of the Laodicea, the rewards of each church appear progressive:

**Ephesus**

- right to eat from the tree of life in paradise

**Smyrna**

- crown of life
- not hurt by second death

**Pergamum**

- hidden manna
- white stone
- new name known only by receiver

**Thyatira**

- authority over nations
- morning star
- rule with iron sceptre
- dash nations to pieces like pottery

**Sardis**

- will walk with me
- dressed in white
- not erase name from book of life
- acknowledge before Father
- acknowledge before angels

**Philadelphia**

- pillar in God’s temple
- never leave temple
- write God’s name
- write name of God’s city
- write my new name
- kept from hour of trial

**Laodicea**

- right to sit with me on my throne

A careful reading will readily show that the rewards are the right source of encouragement for the spiritual condition of each of the seven churches.  That is, the rewards chosen are specifically designed to match the needs of each congregation.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question, "Why are there different rewards for overcomers for the seven churches in Revelation 2 and 3?"

**Answer: The reward is the same for all.**

It's the same reward.

Our goal is to **"overcome."** Read Philippians 3:14,

> I press toward the goal for the prize of the upward call of God in Christ Jesus.

Now if we give Paul credit for writing Hebrews, then he has written half the New Testament. And yet here he is, still pressing on. Aiming  to overcome. Aiming for the prize. The reward.

In each age, the Christian Church has had different issues. In one age, they had to face up to instant death. In our age, it's the lukewarmness to the Bible.

Eight times the Word **"overcomers"** is used in the King James. In Bible symbology, the number 8 represents Jesus and Resurrection.

Here is the key to the reward for the overcomers:  **To be in the first resurrection.**

> Blessed and holy is he that hath part in the first resurrection, on such the second death hath no power,but they shall be priests of God and of Christ, and shall reign with him a thousand years. — *Revelation 20:6*

This says it all.

It's worth a read of [Matthew 25:1-13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025%3A1-13&version=KJV). Note that five Christians missed the boat here. They did not lose salvation, but they missed the reward, like they missed the first bus and would have to wait for the next one. Like a 1000 years. A long wait.

So to recap and to keep it simple, the reward is as shown in Isaiah 40:31,

> But they that wait upon the LORD  shall renew their strength, they shall mount up with wings as eagles, they shall run,and not be weary, and they shall walk, and not faint.

The reward is to rule with Christ for 1000 years. Then the word says it will be offered up to the Father:

> 23 But every man in his own order: Christ the first-fruits; afterward they that are Christ's at his coming.
> 24 Then cometh the end, when he shall have delivered up the kingdom to God, even the Father; when he shall have put down all rule and all authority and power. — 1 Corinthians 15:23-24

Note that (1) "Christ the first-fruit," then (2) "they that are Christ's at His coming."

Note "they that are Christs:"

> And they that are Christ's have crucified the flesh with the affections and lusts. — *Galatians 5:24*

Both Adam and Eve gave way to to lust of the eyes, the flesh and ego:

> And when the woman saw that the tree was good for food **[flesh]**, and that it was pleasant to the eyes **[eyes]**, and a tree to be desired to make one wise **[our self, our ego]**, she took of the fruit thereof, and did eat, and gave also unto her husband with her; and he did eat. — *Genesis 3:6*

1 John 2:16 ties in too:

> For all that is in the world, the lust of the flesh, and the lust of the eyes, and the pride of life, is **not of the Father, but is of the world.**